# use programmatically DOM element of a Component using template variables in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I need to get a handle on a specific DOM element defined in the template of an Angular 2 Component so that I can work with it in my code.
I do not want to use jQuery and ElementRef but rather a variable that can be defined in the template itself to refer to the element I need to work with.
I am able to achieve my goal using an "inner component" that I insert in "my component". I define an Input property in the "inner Component" and bind the template variable to this property; after I do so I can use the DOM element in the code of my "inner component".I am pretty sure though that there is a simpler way to reach the same result. Can anybody advise?
Here a sample code that describes the what I do.
Thanks in advance

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

import {MyInnerComponent} from './myInnerComponent';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: `
    <div #thisElement id="thisElement">
        <my-inner-component [element]="thisElement"></my-inner-component>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: [MyInnerComponent]
})

export class MyComponent { 

} 


import {Component, OnInit, Input} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-inner-component',
  template: `
  `,
    inputs: ['element'],
})

export class MyInnerComponent implements OnInit { 
    @Input() element: any;

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log(this.element);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`AfterViewInit`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/AfterViewInit-interface.html) and [`ViewChild`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/ViewChild-var.html), here is [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/MXDbFoAmgxuwcGe7Hs3Z?p=preview).